# IDEA simplified rule that bring to NPE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

Why IDEA and Checkstyle think that the expression marked below can be simplified?

```
public class MySettingDto {
   private Boolean enabled;

}

...
public void methodA(MySettingDto setting) {
  if (setting == null) {
    return;
  }
  if (setting.getEnable() == true) {  <- CAN BE SIMPIFIED
    ...
  }
}
```

Simplified to `if (setting.getEnable())`? What about getting NPE when `enable` flag is `null`? Maybe it would be better to indicate that `if (setting.getEnable())` is in place, it may throw a NPE?

May someone explain me the logic of this kind of message from IDEA?

Comment: but `if (setting.getEnable() == true)` throws the same NPE when enabled is null, because it does auto unboxing by calling the method `setting.getEnabled().booleanValue()` - if you expect it to be null, then you need to check it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

You can do `if (setting.getEnable()) {…}` since you are already working with a Boolean and don’t need to evaluate it.

And because you’re not working with a primitive Boolean, you can do `if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(setting.getEnable()) {…}`. `.equals()` does a null check internally by using `obj instanceof Boolean` which prevents NullPointerExceptions.